# How to open a new window and multiple urls in Safari with apple script?

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

How do you open a new window in safari and then open multiple tabs with different urls in that window using apple script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way to create a new window in Safari is to use the `make new document` command:

```
make new document at end of documents with properties {URL:the_url}
```

This will create a new window with a single tab pointing to `the_url` and make that window frontmost.  Note that `make new window at end of windows` doesn't work, and just errors out with "AppleEvent handler fails".

Similarly, to create a new tab within a window `w`, you can use `make new tab`:

```
make new tab at end of tabs of w with properties {URL:the_url}
```

This will create a new tab in window `w` at the end of the list of tabs; this tab will be pointing to `the_url`, and it *won't* be the current tab.  Instead of explicitly saying `tabs of w`, you can also use a `tell w` block:

```
tell w
    make new tab at end of tabs with properties {URL:the_url}
end tell
```

That way, `tabs` implicitly refers to `tabs of w`.

Putting this all together, we get the following script.  Given a list of URLs in `the_urls`, it will open all of them in a new window; if `the_urls` is empty, it opens a window with a blank tab.

```
property the_urls : {¬
    "http://stackoverflow.com", ¬
    "http://tex.stackexchange.com", ¬
    "http://apple.stackexchange.com"}

tell application "Safari"
    if the_urls = {} then
        -- If you don't want to open a new window for an empty list, replace the
        -- following line with just "return"
        set {first_url, rest_urls} to {"", {}}
    else
        -- `item 1 of ...` gets the first item of a list, `rest of ...` gets
        -- everything after the first item of a list.  We treat the two
        -- differently because the first item must be placed in a new window, but
        -- everything else must be placed in a new tab.
        set {first_url, rest_urls} to {item 1 of the_urls, rest of the_urls}
    end if

    make new document at end of documents with properties {URL:first_url}
    tell window 1
        repeat with the_url in rest_urls
            make new tab at end of tabs with properties {URL:the_url}
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: what does `window 1` refer to? I substituted that part to `tell front window` to make it more intuitive but your version works even if I had previously opened Safar windows - why? I would have thought the newly opened document would be `window 2`

Comment: @Bn.F76 That's a great question!  `window 1` indeed refers to the frontmost window, so whenever you create a new window it will become `window 1`, and then if you click on another one *that* will become `window 1`, and so on.  I had no idea you could do `front window` instead, that's good to know!

Comment: @Bn.F76 To add: Windows, as well as other objects, also have an `id` property, which seems to grow sequentially like you were expecting, but this isn't really guaranteed.  For instance, right now, when I make a new window in Google Chrome, it's `window id 9779`, and I can address it that way.  Its only tab is `tab id 9780`, and is accessible as either `tab 1 of window 1` or `tab id 9780 of window 9779`.  If I then create a newer window, it's `window id 9781` with `tab id 9782`.  So these numbers are like what you were thinking of, but more arbitrary, and not the usual means of address.

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "Safari"
  activate
  set the URL of document 1 to "http://www.XXXXXXX.com"
  my new_tab()
  set the URL of document 1 to "http://www.XXXXXX.com"
end tell
on new_tab()
  tell application "Safari" to activate
  tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
      «event prcsclic» «class menI» "New Tab" of «class menE» "File" of «class mbar» 1
    end tell
  end tell
end new_tab
```

Replace the X's with whatever sites you want and keep repeating the code (my new_tab() and set the URL... lines) for each page you'd like to have open. 
Referring to [this page.](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030414185226343)
Correct me if this isn't what you were talking about.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Pugmatt. It's close to what I want. Your script opens the url in an existing Safari window - I want to open then in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Base on Pugmatt's answer I got the following to work...

```
on run {input, parameters}
  tell application "Safari"
  activate
    make new document with properties {URL:"http://www.apple.com"}
    my new_tab()
    set the URL of document 1 to "http://www.example.com"
  end tell
end run
on new_tab()
  tell application "Safari" to activate
  tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
      «event prcsclic» «class menI» "New Tab" of «class menE» "File" of «class mbar» 1
    end tell
  end tell
end new_tab
```

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way of you this.